# Run attrib on a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, php, wine, file-attributes

I have a strange question: if I install `wine` on Linux will I be able to do a shell exec in `php` to add the proper attributes to a folder so when it is transferred to Windows it is hidden?

For example: `shell_exec('wine attrib +h folder');` ?

I have been trying to find a way to create Windows hidden files in Linux and then transfer them to Windows.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not work the same way as windows does, which is why it isn't working.

In windows, you can add flags to a file or folder, where one is the hidden attribute.

In linux, the hidden attribute is set by renaming the file or folder. Any file  or folder that starts with a . will automatically get the hidden attribute.

Example  : To make `myfile.ext` hidden, you would rename it to `.myfile.ext`
Example 2: To make `myfolder` hidden, you would rename it to `.myfolder`

Comment: The "." method is only to de-clutter results nothing more. It does not hide a file (otherwise `ls -la` would not show the file). Example: `cd ~ && mkdir tmp && touch tmp/1 && chmod 000 tmp` would make "1" invisible and `chattr +i tmp` would make the chmod irreversable by anyone but the admin. Not a single "." used. So "There is no other way to make a file or folder hidden in the linux filesystem." is 100% wrong.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the remark for it being the only way.

Comment: So i cant use a program like java to add a hidden flag to a folder in my ubuntu machine before downloading it